# "Namespace is not bound" in resources xml file when code inspecting with Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-resources

When I do inpect code in Android Studio it throws this
"Unbound XML namespace prefix - Namespace is not bound" for my string and color res XML files. This one for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="registro">#e73020</color>
<color name="entorno">#e73020</color>
</resources>
```

It's not an error, it compiles and executes well, but I would like to know why code inspection marks this as a warning or something.

I've read [This here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564149/why-am-i-getting-this-error-unbound-xml-namespace-prefix), but it is not fully answered in 3 years, so i decided to post a similar question with a different situation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting this error "Unbound XML namespace prefix"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564149/why-am-i-getting-this-error-unbound-xml-namespace-prefix)

Comment: @cricket_007 the op is interested in a lint warning, not an error.